# How to access nested associative array data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, nested, associative

I have an indexed array that contains a nested associative array AND a nested indexed array:

```
$myArray = array ( 
    0 => array (
        'name' => 'Paul', 
        'age' => '23', 
        'hobbies' => array ( 
            0 => 'basketball',
        ), 
        'pets' => 'dog',
    ),
);
```

How can I access all of these values and convert them into variables?

Comment: You shouldn't, just use the array whenever you need any of its values.

Comment: I'm having a problem with that. For example,  
`echo $myArray[0]['name'];`  
doesn't output what I'd expect.

Comment: What does it output?  When I tried it it output "Paul".  And @jeroen is right, you'll just clutter up the variable space if you start trying to convert an array into variables.

Comment: I think the problem is that what I'm trying to do is convert an entire string into an array. I'll probably have to split up the string via "explode" or "preg_split".

Answer (score 3):

You can just access from Array

Write your array like this

```
$myArray = [
  0 => [
      'name' => 'Paul',
      'age' => '23',
      'hobbies' => [
              0 => 'basketball',
            ],
      'pets' => 'dog'
    ]
];
```

Suppose you want to access name of first elements

```
echo $myArray[0]['name']; // it will print 'Paul'
echo $myArray[0]['hobbies'][0]; // it will print basketball
```

Now you can fetch like above.

Comment: When I do that, I just get the letter 'a', which I'm assuming is from the word 'array'.

Comment: You can copy & paste my code here. http://phpfiddle.org/ . Run it. I have just checked its working correctly